# lua to sql An item with the same key has already been added. Key: date

Tags: mysql, sql, lua

I am getting an error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAxlV.png)

When trying to select the data from database in lua script:

```
local convictions = MySQL.Sync.fetchAll('SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s") AS date from lspd_user_judgments WHERE userId = @owner ORDER BY date DESC', {
                        ['@owner'] = userData.identifier
                    });
```

does anyone have any suggestions on how I could fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have a field called `date`, the `*` is returning a map for `date` to the date value. And your `DATE_FORMAT` is returning map for `date` to its return value.

Lua can't handle two columns the same.

Its unclear why you need `DATE_FORMAT`, try your code without it, surely the `date` type that lua associates with datetime is a) usuable as a date or b) in this format already. Try without it.

If its really needed for some reason, `DATE_FORMAT(...) AS date_formatted` is an alternate that returns it as a non-conflicting name.